# Positioning problems CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get my elements centered in one block like this www.spookycraft.net But I haven't been able to figure it out. My code: http://jsfiddle.net/7PP9K/1/

raw code:

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title> Wandercraft Network </title>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.slide-up-boxes a{
display:block;
width:300px;
height:300px;
background: #eee;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
overflow:hidden;
}

.slide-up-boxes h5{
height:300px;
width:300px;
text-align:center;
line-height:150px; 
-webkit-transition: margin-top 0.3s linear ;
background-color:#white;
}

.slide-up-boxes a:hover h5{
margin-top:-300px;

}

.slide-up-boxes div{
text-align:center;
height:300px;
width:300px;
opacity:0;
background-color:orange;
-webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear ;
}

.slide-up-boxes a:hover div{
-webkit-transform: rotate(0);
opacity:1;
}

.slide-up-boxes{
 margin:auto;
}




</style>

</head>

<body>


<div id="page-wrap">

<section class="slide-up-boxes">

<a href="www.reddit.com">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/PVP.png">
<div> 
<h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
 </div>
</a>

</div>

<section class="slide-up-boxes">
<a href="www.reddit.com">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Kingdoms.png">
<div> 
<h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
 </div>
</a>

<section class="slide-up-boxes">
<a href="www.reddit.com">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Survival.png">
<div> 
<h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
 </div>
</a>

<section class="slide-up-boxes">
<a href="www.reddit.com">
<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85261154/Factions.png">
<div> 
<h5> <img src="http://www.backbonetechnology.com/media/blog-html5-logo.png"> </h5>
 </div>
</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'll be updating this post if I find an answer thank you for reading.

Comment: Do you mean you want the 4 images shown as a 2x2 grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle.

I've closed the sections and added some CSS to allow for the same presentation as the spookycraft website.

Have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7PP9K/4/

The key changes:

```
body{
    width:960px;
}

#page-wrap{
    width:620px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.slide-up-boxes {
    margin:5px;
    width:300px;
    float:left;
}
```

edit: wrong jsfiddle link, now updated

Comment: the body{ width:960px; } actually pushed it to the left, I removed it, It worked perfectly, You were a great help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to center positioning block elements is

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Just add that to your anchor css (.slide-up-boxes a) or whatever element you want centered and it should work. Make sure it has a fixed width too.

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent a fixed width and center it by automated margins:

```
#page-wrap {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/7PP9K/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS :

.slide-up-boxes a {
    float:left;             // changes made
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#page-wrap{
    width:620px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
body{
    width:1200px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7PP9K/7/)